# Merge sort segmentation fault with large array size

Tags: c++, mergesort

I have a merge sort program that works just fine with small array sizes, but when I try to sort an array of size 1000, I get a segmentation fault. After attempting to debug the program, it appeared that the seg fault happened somewhere around the code block `while(i < last1)`, but I'm having trouble figuring out what's going wrong.

```
void mergeSort(long array[], long last1, long last2){
  //Elements in first, second, and merged arrays, respectively                                                                       
  long i = 0;
  long j = last1;
  long k = 0;

  long* temp = new long[last2];

  //Copy the smaller of the two values i and j into the new temp array                                                               
  while(i < last1 && j < last2){
    if(array[i] < array[j]){
      temp[k] = array[i];
      ++i;
      ++k;
    }
    else{
      temp[k] = array[j];
      ++j;
      ++k;
    }
  }

  //Copy the remaining largest elements of the two arrays to temp[]                                                                  
  while(i < last1){
    temp[k] = array[i];
    ++i;
    ++k;
  }
  while(j < last2){
    temp[k] = array[j];
    ++j;
    ++k;
  }

  //Copy the merged elements of the temp array back into the original array                                                          
  for(long m=0; m<last2; ++m){
    array[m] = temp[m];
  }
}


int main(){

 //create array here called array and fill will values

  for(long i=1; i<n; i=(2*i)){
    for(long j=0; j<(n-1); j=(j+(2*i))){
      long end = ((2*i) < (n-j)) ? (2*i) : (n - j);
        function.mergeSort(&array[j], i, end);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do realize that when you merge your two arrays into `temp`, the total length will be the sum of the two inputs, right?

Comment: Also, I see you `new[] temp` but not `delete[] temp`.

Comment: This really doesn't look like a normal invocation of merge sort.

Comment: That isn't a mergesort algorithm; its a **merge** algorithm. You're missing the entire front-side of mergesort, namely the proper partitioning mechanics.